# Automatic Navigation Back in Flutter after PayPal Payment Completion

Tags: flutter, paypal, navigation, payment

I have implemented a PayPal payment flow in my Flutter app using the flutter_paypal package. The payment process works correctly, and once the payment is completed successfully, I want the app to navigate back automatically to the previous screen.

I have two widgets related to the PayPal payment process:

UsePaypal: This widget handles the payment initiation and displays the PayPal checkout page using a webview. It also provides a callback for handling successful, canceled, and error cases after the payment process.

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (BuildContext context) => UsePaypal(
      // ... other parameters ...
```

the above is how we use paypal flutter in webview

Since I can't edit the code inside a package, I am facing an issue with automatically navigating back to the previous screen after completing a payment using the flutter_paypal package